# How to send large, frequent xml data from javascript to a c++ http server

Tags: c++, http, post, server

In my project I want to send possibly large and frequent XML data to a custom server written in c++. I don't want to use Apache and CGI because the data is too frequent to be starting a CGI process for every request. I would prefer if the data was recieved directly in the c++ code that will process the data and send a reply.

I started out by using libmicrohttpd for the c++ server but now I believe it won't be possible because it doesn't give access to the raw POST data. I started looking for another library but I can't seem to find a c++ library that does this. Can anyone suggest a c++ http server library that has access to the raw post data?

Here is the code I intended to start with. It is one of the example files provided in the source code of libmicrohttpd. [Post Example from libmicrohttpd library](https://gnunet.org/svn/libmicrohttpd/src/examples/post_example.c)

Edit:

A little more context.

From what I understand to access the post data in libmicrohttpd you create MHD_PostProcessor function that gets called incrementally as the post data is received in chunks. But in the example below it only shows how to get post data in the form of key value pairs. But I can't see how to get the data from a post.

The example implements the MHD_PostProcessor as post_iterator. See the definition of

```
static int post_iterator(void *cls,
       enum MHD_ValueKind kind,
       const char *key,
       const char *filename,
       const char *content_type,
       const char *transfer_encoding,
       const char *data, uint64_t off, size_t size) {
...
```

in the example posted above. You will see it only shows how to iterate the key value pairs.

Comment: Are you limited to http server? can you use a non http server that supports streaming? and can use use javascript sockets? If yes to all those then perhaps go away from http and start streaming data. Perhaps  you are over thinking it. If the server sends a flag that it supports compression, modern browsers will compress the data you send.

Comment: @over_optimistic Yes I was trying to implement it all with HTTP so I don't have another dependencybut now it's seeming like my only option.  I am just surprised that there isn't a C++ library that handles a simple http POST with xml data.

Answer (score 0):

MHD does give you access to the raw POST data, just grab it from "upload_data" directly instead of passing it to the MHD_PostProcessor.  MHD will give you the uploaded POST stream incrementally by calling your main request processing callback repeatedly with more and more POST data being given to you raw, unprocessed in "upload_data".